# Convert body heat to light

Tags: peltier, thermocouple

What thermoelectric device would I use to power one white LED generated by the body heat of one square centimeter skin on a hand.

That is, I wish to power one white LED from the heat generated by one square centimeter of hand skin. What device could I use?

Comment: Magic Device ??

Comment: Such a device isn't possible. Question should be closed.

Comment: @LeonHeller  This is not the finest question because of insufficient preliminary research and because of the way the question is formulated.  Overall, I don't argue that I got closed.  Having said that, the fact that a certain idea  doesn't appear realistic or practical by itself doesn't mean that the question should be closed.  There still may be room for a useful conversation about why a device would not be practical.

Answer (score 4):

Basal metabolic rate of an adult human body is approximately 100 W. Let's assume that all this power is dissipated through skin (which is an optimistic assumption, because lungs dissipate a lot too). Human skin has area of 18 580 cm². In the first approximation, you have 0.005 W/cm² to play with.

This is before the conversion from thermal to electrical, which will be far from 100%.

Comment: "far from 100%" indeed - 2% to 4% typically. Assuming a suitable cold source to maintain a temperature gradient.

Answer (score 0):

Thermocouples produce voltage based on a temperature differential.
The differential would be ok in a winter, but would disappear in the summer.
It would take many thermocouples in series to get the necessary voltage to make the LED conduct.  It would be possible to make a flashlight powered by the heat of a palm of hand, but it would work only in the cold.

Comment: Please reread the OP. You have not understood the power limitations he is proposing. Even in the Arctic he won't get what he wants.