# Bodyheat powered microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, low-power, peltier

[Old Post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/260894/grade-school-science-experiment-peltier-module-and-led) and [even older Post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/147964/convert-body-heat-to-light) I came across before posting this question. The answers by McMahon and Alexeev are pretty much what I was thinking:

human energy source: ~100 W
skin surface: ~1.75 m<sup>2</sup>
⇒ ~57 W/m<sup>2</sup> = 5.7 mW/cm<sup>2</sup> (call it 5 mW/cm<sup>2</sup>)

skin temp: 35°C
air temp: 25°C
⇒ carnot efficiency: 3.24% (call it 3%)

[Peltier efficiency](https://dewiki.de/Lexikon/Peltier-Element): ~10%

⇒ 5 mW/cm<sup>2</sup> × 3% × 10% = 15 µW/cm<sup>2</sup>

common Peltier size: 4 cm × 4 cm = 16 cm<sup>2</sup>
⇒ 240 µW

---

Now to the truly electrical part that I know the least of, apart from playing around with low-powering Atmega chips, some time ago:
It seems to be common for [ultra-lower-power MCUs](https://www.engineersgarage.com/project-stm32-low-power-modes-analysis/) to only need 3.3 µA in standby and 12.7 mA when running.

So:
240 µW/3.6 V = 66.7 µA
12700 × x + 3.3 × (1-x) = 66.7 ⇒ 0.50% on-time (or somewhat less with transformational losses)

So I would get around 300 ms of calculations every minute, not much, but it's something.

---

Do I miss something obvious, except for a good thermal interface between the skin and the Peltier, that would prevent me from powering a MCU like the STM32L0 just using a Peltier and some sort of power-buffer glued to my forearm?

Comment: Have you checked on the web (elsewhere) to see what people have actually achieved? I'm pretty sure this has been done. And someone (more than one of them) should have a few published papers on the topic. If you have not examined the literature on this, you should do so. Some thoughts to add. Dissipation per unit area is different on different places of the body. Identify key areas to target. Dissipation occurs three ways: convection, conduction, and radiation. You assume much, blindly applying carnot and peltier. You can and should examine better ultra low power devices and get numbers.

Comment: Finally, there is an entire industry (more than one, actually) being built around micropower energy harvesting and a great deal of work has already gone into it. You should study what's available and what might apply in your circumstance. Also, learn from them about what they've achieved, separately from the research papers on the topic. It's out there. And you can call and talk with engineers to pick up more details. You need do ALL of this, just to start. Make contact. Talk with people out there. Write down everything you learn. You don't need to start from scratch.

Comment: My guess is that your power/area ratio is wildly optimistic. Most of the heat generated by the body leaves via the breath, not the skin. You'd be better off just blowing into a small wind generator every now and then instead.

Comment: Powering microcontrollers or sensors from body heat has been done before.  With respect to your specific calculations, your assumed power harvested from body heat is a bit high compared to real devices, but otherwise that analysis looks correct to me.

Comment: Your calculations went astray when you computed the size of the Peltier, I've fixed up the numbers (and the formatting).

Comment: There are plenty of lower-power MCUs out there. As just one example, the MSP430 only needs about 200-300 uA in active mode @ 1 MHz, so using your numbers, you could easily get 20% "on" time at that frequency, or 100% duty cycle at a lower frequency. Microchip "nanoWatt" devices go as low as 50 uA / MHz active current.

Comment: In this scenario most of the energy is probably used up by your display, or communications interfaces rather than the MCU.

Comment: I don't think you missed anything. Good luck with the electronics, you will need to be very careful about leaking power, but it's probably possible.